# GWBASIC File I need to understand the equations behind this code but I cannot interpret it, I can run it

Tags: basic

Can someone tell me how to open up this old GWBASIC file. I can run it but what I to know the equations and code behind it.

```
"RANGE ADJUSTMENT PROGRAM"·(‘:‘:‘Ý2…
"ENTER RANGE QTY ________ ",QTA!
<…"ENTER PRICE ____________ ",PA!:‘*F…
"ENTER SECOND QTY _______ ",QTB!QP…
"ENTER SECOND PRICE _____ ",PB!:‘s
ZTVAç(QTA!ëPA!):TVBç(QTB!ëPB!)‚
dTVçTVBêTVA”
nLABORçQTBêQTA§
xLABORçTVìLABORÍ
‚‘"LABOR IS ______________ ";LABORç
ŒSUçTVAê(LABORë(QTA!))
–‘"SETUP IS ______________ ";SU:‘:‘1
…"ENTER DESIRED RANGE QTY";QTCE
ªPCçSUìQTCéLABORi
´‘:‘"PRICE FOR ABOVE QTY IS ";PCy
¾PDçPCë33
È‘:‘"PRICE AT 15% MARKUP IS ";PDã
Ò‘:…"ENTER (R)-(ANOTHER RANGE) (N)-(ANOTHER PART) (Q)-(QUIT)",RES$é
Ü‘þæ‹ RES$ç"R" ‰ ‚
ð‹ RES$ç"N" ‰ 
'ú‹ RES$ç"Q" Í þƒ1‰ Ò
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a .bas file and you have the GW-BASIC interpreter. What you can do is run the code, and save it in ASCII format instead of binary format which is default. You would do this by appending the A option. `SAVE "C:\myfile.bas", A` should do what you need. Open up the file in any text editor and there is your code.